# Python Selenium selecting div class

Tags: python, selenium

So I'm writing a script using Selenium but I got stuck at finding a div class.

The structure on the website is like this:

```
<div class="field first_name">
    <input type="text" placeholder="First Name"></input>
</div>`
```

Already tried something like `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//field[@first_name]")`
But it didn't work for some reason, maybe I did it wrong or have to it in a different way.

Anyone got a clue?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are mixing class and xpath locators in an unsupported way!

Either of the following will work:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'first_name')]")
driver.find_element_by_class_name("first_name")
```

You might want to consider reading some [documentation](http://zvon.org/comp/r/tut-XPath_1.html) on XPath, and perhaps [Selenium locators](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/02_selenium_ide.jsp#locating-elements) in general.

Comment: Thank you very much friend for both the solution and documentation links.