# select single element and its value - powershell script to python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this script in powershell to get value of visitors at webpage:

```
$visitors = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://footballarena.org
$visitors = $visitors.AllElements | where class -EQ "right" | select -ExpandProperty innertext
$visitors = $visitors -replace '\D+'
$visitors | Export-Csv $env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\export.txt
```

The output is only numerical value of single DIV class "right"

Now I need to do the same script in python.
I can read and store the page:

```
web = urllib.request.urlopen("https://footballarena.org").read()
```

Now I need to select value of "161" from this single class:

```
<div class="right">161 online</div>
```

I found this question, but I'm not sure how to use it - [Python Selenium selecting div class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30874690/python-selenium-selecting-div-class)

Could anybody help please?

Comment: Selenium may work too but seems like perfect use case for [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)

Comment: thank you for hint - I will try to study it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can do it with [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/), install with `pip3 install beautifulsoup4`, then something like:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request

myurl = "https://footballarena.org"

html_doc = urllib.request.urlopen(myurl).read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')

result = soup.findAll("div", { "class" : "right" })

print(result[0].text.split()[0])
```

outputs:

```
206 # users currently online
```

Can probably be improved, but that's the general idea. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you so much! I've just began with python and you helped me a lot!

Comment: Very welcome, glad to be able to help you! Hope your learning python goes well, this was the first time I tried beautifulsoup, but that's because python makes learning new packages easy, quick and fun. Cheers and good luck!